# No logro completar select dependiente en formulario de búsqueda symfony 2

Tags: php, jquery, symfony2

Estoy intentando agregar un formulario de búsqueda a un proyecto Symfony 2.8, con el típico 'select' dependiente entre país y provincia.
No se como manejar los eventos pre_set del formulario.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora, pero aún no se separar la lógica de los eventos:

```
class BuscarInstitucionType extends AbstractType {

      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {
          $builder->add('provincias', EntityType::class, array(
              'label' => 'Provincias',
              'class' => 'AppBundle:EstructuraOrganizativa',
              'empty_data' => null,
              'placeholder' => 'Seleccione',
              'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)
      {
          return $er->createQueryBuilder('prov')
                          ->join('prov.tipoEstructuraOrganizativa', 'teo')
                          ->where('teo.id = 2')
                         ->addOrderBy('prov.id', 'ASC');
     },
              'choice_label' => 'title',
          ));

          $builder->addEventListener(
                  FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event)
          {
              $form = $event->getForm();
              $data = $event->getData();

              $prov = $data['provincias'];

              $form->add('municipios', EntityType::class, array(
                  'label' => 'Municipios',
                  'class' => 'AppBundle:EstructuraOrganizativa',
                  'empty_data' => null,
                  'choice_label' => 'title',
                  'placeholder' => '',
                  'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use($prov)
          {
              $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('mcpio')
                              ->join('mcpio.tipoEstructuraOrganizativa', 'teo')
                              ->where('mcpio.parent = :prov')->setParameter('prov', $prov);

              return $qb;
          },
              ));
          });
      }    }
```

Este es el action que devuelve el json con los municipios de la provincia seleccionada:

```
public function municipiosPorProvinciaAction(Request $request)
     {
         if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
         {
             $id = intval($request->get('id', 0));
             $provincia = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:EstructuraOrganizativa')->findOneJoinTipoEstructuraOrganizativa($id);
             if (is_null($provincia) || $provincia->getTipoEstructuraOrganizativa()->getId() !== 2)
             {
                 return new Response('No se encontró la provincia seleccionada', 404);
             }

             $municipiosAsociados = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:EstructuraOrganizativa')->municipiosPorProvincia($provincia);

             $responseArray = array();
             foreach ($municipiosAsociados as $mun)
             {
                 $responseArray[] = array(
                     "id" => $mun->getId(),
                     "title" => $mun->getTitle()
                 );
             }

             return new JsonResponse($responseArray);
         } else
         {
             throw $this->createNotFoundException("Recurso no encontrado.");
         }
     }
```

Y este es el action que muestra la vista del formulario de búsqueda y a la vez. Debería procesar el formulario si la petición se hace con el método POST y devolver los resultados.

```
 public function directorioAction(Request $request)
     {
         if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
         {
             $formBusqueda = $this->createForm(\AppBundle\Form\BuscarInstitucionType::class, null,
 array(
                 'action' => $this->generateUrl('app_directorio'),
                 'attr' => array('id' => 'id_buscar_institucion'),
             ));

             if ($request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_GET))
             {
                 return $this->render('AppBundle:EstructuraOrganizativa:directorio.html.twig',
 array(
                             'formBusqueda' => $formBusqueda->createView()
                 ));
             } else if ($request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST))
             {
                 $formBusqueda->handleRequest($request);
                 $respuesta = new Response(); //                if ($formBusqueda->isValid()) //                {
                 $data = $formBusqueda->getData();
                 $idProv = intval($data['provincias']->getId());
                 $idMun = intval($data['municipios']->getId());
                 $respuesta->setContent($idMun); //                } else //                { //                   
 $respuesta->setContent("Error al procesar la solicitud"); //          
 $respuesta->setStatusCode(500); // //                    return
 $respuesta; //                }

                 return $respuesta;
            } else
             {
                 return new Response("Error en la solicitud", 500);
             }
         } else
         {
             throw $this->createNotFoundException("Recurso no encontrado.");
        }
     }
```

Y el resto es el ajax que popula el segundo select con el json de los municipios.

Como el evento pre del formulario está mal desarrollado, no me es posible obtener el id de la provincia seleccionada (como pueden apreciar las provincias se cargan al iniciar el formulario), y se obtienen para el select desde un query_builder porque están en la base de datos como una estructura anidada las provincias y municipios.

Answer (score 1):

la solución encontrada fue sencilla: repetir el mismo código del evento `PRE_SET_DATA` del formulario, pero para le evento `PRE_SUBMIT`. de forma tal que garantice que el formulario symfony popule los datos de las entidades asociadas antes de hacer el submit.

publico el código de cómo quedó la clase `BuscarInstitucionType`:

```
class BuscarInstitucionType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('provincias', EntityType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Provincias',
            'class' => 'AppBundle:EstructuraOrganizativa',
            'empty_data' => null,
            'placeholder' => 'Seleccione',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)
    {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('prov')
                        ->join('prov.tipoEstructuraOrganizativa', 'teo')
                        ->where('teo.id = 2')
                        ->addOrderBy('prov.id', 'ASC');
    },
            'choice_label' => 'title',
        ));

        $builder->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event)
        {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            $prov = $data['provincias'];

            $form->add('municipios', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Municipios',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:EstructuraOrganizativa',
                'empty_data' => null,
                'choice_label' => 'title',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use($prov)
        {
            $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('mcpio')
                            ->join('mcpio.tipoEstructuraOrganizativa', 'teo')
                            ->where('mcpio.parent = :prov')->setParameter('prov', $prov);

            return $qb;
        },
            ));
        });

        $builder->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event)
        {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            $prov = $data['provincias'];

            $form->add('municipios', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Municipios',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:EstructuraOrganizativa',
                'empty_data' => null,
                'choice_label' => 'title',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use($prov)
        {
            $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('mcpio')
                            ->join('mcpio.tipoEstructuraOrganizativa', 'teo')
                            ->where('mcpio.parent = :prov')->setParameter('prov', $prov);

            return $qb;
        },
            ));
        });
    }

}
```